How to access StringProperty when it is in array?
I am trying to access values inside of StringProperty. When I am trying to access it directly, I have no problem, but when I save it in array, I am able to access only the object and not the value inside of the object.
    var1 = StringProperty("something1")
    var2 = StringProperty("something2")
    var3 = StringProperty("something3")

    arr = [var1, var2, var3]

    def send2(self):
        print(self.arr[0])

Output:
StringProperty name=var1>

I was expecting output:
something1
I have tried to access value with:
    def send(self):
        for prop_name in self.arr:
            value = getattr(self, prop_name)
            print(f"{prop_name}: {value}")

But this code output to error:
TypeError: attribute name must be string, not 'kivy.properties.StringProperty'
For context: I am trying to save a bunch of TextInput variables in .csv, and I want to populate .csv via loop. Probably something like this:
for value in self.arr:
   writer.writerow(value)

I am probably missing some key information about property objects.

is there a reason why you use StringProperty instead of str?

@Aemyl yes, I need to display text in UI written in .kv, value itself can change through the lifespan of program. This was recommended to me as way to go around this.

this sounds like an additional requirement that should be included in your question. How exactly are var1 etc. entangled with the UI? How do you save the user input in these properties? How many strings do you want your program to support? up to three or arbitrarily many? If you want a good answer, provide all the relevant details.

When you have a class with StringProperty attributes like this:
class Example:
    var1 = StringProperty("something1")
    var2 = StringProperty("something2")
    var3 = StringProperty("something3")

the StringProperty constructor adds getters and setters, so you can do this:
>>> example = Example()
>>> print(example.var1)
something1
>>> 

I think that's not really what you want for your program. The idea to use a list is good, but I would simply put builtin str objects into this list:
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        # set this in the __init__ since lists are mutable
        self.arr = ["something1", "something2", "something3"]

    def show_values(self):
        for value in self.arr:
            print(value)


Thank you for response, unfortunately this is not possible for me because I want to keep those values mutable so user can change it from UI in the future (sorry for not clarifying that beforehand).
I was playing with idea to save all of those values in separate variables with string type just so I can save them in array, but because of mutable nature of those variables it might be quiet performance heavy and wasteful.

self.arr is a list, which is mutable. You can just use self.arr[0] = ... to change the first value, for example.

Okay might not be answer I've looked for but now I at least understand where is the problem.
When I am referencing to var1 or var2 directly within the class (but outside of a method) I am for some reason referring to "StringProperty" object themselves and not the values they hold and those property object is what is stored in 'arr' list. I guess it is caused by reactivity and binding properties of kivy objects, but i have no proof of that.
Solution 1. is create array in method and call for variables using .self
class SimpleLayout(
    var1 = StringProperty("something1")
    var2 = StringProperty("something2")
    var3 = StringProperty("something3")
    var4 = StringProperty("something4")

    def get_property_values(self):
        return [self.var1, self.var2, self.var3, self.var4]

    def send(self):
        arr = self.get_property_values()
        print(arr)

solution 2. is somehow levarage auto-update feature of ListProperty, in init() bind variables to ListProperty and call it from other methods, but I was unable to make it work
